# PostgreSQL How to do IF expression is null?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to make a conditional Select statement that creates a table if the table does not exist, but this does not seem to work for some reason?

```
IF SELECT to_regclass('public.entityName') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE |entityName| 
        (....)
END
END IF
```

Comment: Why not simply use `create table if not exists`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what I ended up doing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended doing thins

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.name
    (...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to return true/false:

```
SELECT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM pg_tables
  WHERE schemaname = 'schema'
  AND tablename = 'table'
);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I am looking for a table not a database... @ChechoCZ

Comment: Is your table in camel Case? Like 'myTable'? In that case, you should wrap the table name in double quotes. Have you tried it?

Comment: it is lower case... i just want to see if it there and if not create it

Comment: Kafka, I'll edit the answer with the solution. Hope it helps...

Comment: I need to trigger something if does not exist? how do i do that then? @ChechoCZ

Comment: You can do exactly what you were doing but instead of `SELECT to_regclass('public.entityName') IS NULL` you put the code I posted in the answer. You check if it exists, and proceed as you need to.